# WYSIWYG recommendations for my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, wysiwyg

I'm working on a Rails project and I'm in need of a user-friendly WYSIWYG. I'll say this about the type of people using it: Whatever you think of as user-friendly, perhaps think one step below that (not an insult, just a realization).

Ideally, I'd like something where one could have basic functionality (lists, links, bold, italic) and see in real-time. Kind of like OH MY GOSH IT'S RIGHT HERE IN STACK OVERFLOW AS I CREATE THIS POST.

So, um, yeah: something like this would be excellent (although I'd prefer the windows be side-by-side rather than this editor-on-top situation, but I won't be picky).

Comment: "What HTML editor is used by Stack Overflow?" - http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43024/154448

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest to use gem **[ckeditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor)** it's really perfect solution, i used it recently in my Rails 3.2 project

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out shortly and report back.

Comment: I tried out this gem. It has fantastic front end and tons of opportunities/features but I didnt got it working in production mode because required assets could not be served with my configuration

Answer (score 3):

A pretty cool and fancy one is [Sir Trevor JS](https://github.com/madebymany/sir-trevor-js). There is also a [gem](https://github.com/madebymany/sir-trevor-rails)

Answer (score 2):

We use [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) quite a bit.

No unbelievable feature set or anything, but it does have a nice jQuery integration plugin (which goes a long way for us).

The live preview functionality seems [very doable](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=tinymce%20live%20preview).

Answer (score 2):

If your project is non commercial you can use this

[Froala](https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-rails)

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [Bootsy](https://github.com/volmer/bootsy). It's simple and easy to use, however I have not been able to get the "image" upload => carrierwave to store on S3 servers.  But everything else with it is fantastic.

Comment: looks pretty cool, some toolbar features wont display with bootstrap4 alpha6

Comment: Its been a while since I've used it. Not sure how well it works nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Trix](https://trix-editor.org/) by Basecamp:

> Trix is an open-source project from Basecamp, the creators of Ruby on Rails. Millions of people trust their text to Basecamp, and we built Trix to give them the best possible editing experience.

Comment: pros and cons of trix?

Comment: Pro: very easy to use. Con: although it covers what you need most of the times, it doesn't support many formatting options in its toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Mercury` its a full featured HTML5 editor

```
gem 'mercury-rails'
rails generate mercury:install
```

http://jejacks0n.github.io/mercury/

github: https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury

Answer (score 0):

Old question but check out **froala**: https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-rails

and the plugins main homepage https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor